# "formatDiagnostics is not a function" when I try to run my code with "ts-node index.ts" on Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ts-node

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:857
const diagnosticText = formatDiagnostics(diagnostics, diagnosticHost);
                     
TypeError: formatDiagnostics is not a function
at createTSError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:857:28)
at reportTSError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:863:19)
at createFromPreloadedConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:874:36)
at phase4 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:543:44)
at bootstrap (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:95:10)
at main (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:55:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:800:3)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
```

And I don't know how to fix it. Please, help me!!!
My node version is 18.18, typescript version is 5.3.3, ts-node is 10.9.2

Or the issue depends on the versions of languages?

Comment: have you searched the internets for *formatDiagnostics is not a function*?

Comment: Yes, i did but did not find the answer at all. After that I deleted and reinstall typescript and ts-node three or fourth times it worked finally :) Thanks to all!!!

Answer (score 0):

As the [similar issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1124) states, your development environment seems to be broken in some way. Personally, I couldn't recreate this behavior with the matching stack:

```
❯ npx ts-node -vv
ts-node v10.9.2
node v18.18.2
compiler v5.3.3
```

The ts-node docs [states](https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/troubleshooting#syntaxerror) that any error except `TSError` come from node and can be caused by bugs in your code or configuration.

Here are couple of possible solutions:

- Try different version of node (you can use `nvm`), especially if you have multiple environments installed
- Review your code and configuration files
- Remove `typescript` and `ts-node` from `node_modules` directory and try:

  ```
  npm install ts-node --save-dev
  npm install -g typescript --save-dev
  ```

Comment: Thanks to your answer. It worked me after deleting and reinstalling  few times :)